# Problems with broken packages

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install musescore but this error comes ahead:

[image]

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and then try again this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and finally update your packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If this doesn't work I'd advise you to install synaptic package manager (it's a gui client) and it will be way easier to manually remove the broken packages.

To install synaptic just run this command:

sudo apt-get install synaptic

And it should appear on your slingshot on the system tools tab with an old weird icon.

Answer (score 0):

Install them manually, that should fix it.

Comment: If you mean by that to install libqt4-scripttools by sudo apt-get install libqt4-scripttools, yes I have tried it and I have more broken packages and more unmet dependencies

Comment: Which packages are now required?

Comment: for [sudo apt-get install libqt4-scripttools] unmet dependencies:  libqt4-script, libqtcore4 and libqtgui. If I try to install them manually by apt-get, they are already the newest version.

Comment: What do you get for apt-get -f? Or by removing all packages, and reinstalling them?

Comment: apt-get install -f: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 128 not upgraded.  reinstall packages: problems with unmet dependencies and broken packages, again.